# How to make text layer spot channel in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, spot-color

I am working with a UV printer which requires my white colour on Photoshop to be on a spot channel. What is the correct way to convert a text layer into a spot channel? It seems that to make it spot, it becomes a selection which means I can no longer change the text.

Comment: A spot colour can't be applied to an editable text layer in Photoshop. Channels in Photoshop are raster only. Better to do this in Illustrator or InDesign. Import any raster image you need, then type some text on top, set the text colour to a spot colour.  The text will still be editable. If you don't have access to these, it could also be done in Scribus, which is like InDesign, and supports spot colours.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. Spot *channels* can not contain live, editable text. One creates a *selection* based upon text, then fills the spot *channel* based upon the selection. Then hides the text *layer*.

This is a partial reason a 2-file workflow is desired, if not required. One file containing all the layers for construction. Then another file that's been flattened for reproduction. This way you have a working file so you can redo some steps should things like text need to be changed in the future.